# Rumen and custom counters

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Rumen to extract information from the job history to .json format.
This works fine for default counters and params.
However, I could not see the custom counters that I have added to my mappers.

I manage to see those custom counters via the web based history interface, but they don't appear in the generated .json file by Rumen.

Any idea on how to extract all (default + custom) counters from the job history by using Rumen ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but judging from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-rumen/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tools/rumen), currently there is no built-in way to access custom counters.

Classes like [LoggedTask](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/tools/rumen/LoggedTask.html) or [LoggedTaskAttempt](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/tools/rumen/LoggedTaskAttempt.html) expose the standard counters only. However, custom counters seem to be captured and stored in [ParsedTask](http://fossies.org/dox/hadoop-1.1.2/classorg_1_1apache_1_1hadoop_1_1tools_1_1rumen_1_1ParsedTask.html) or [ParsedTaskAttempt](http://fossies.org/dox/hadoop-1.1.2/classorg_1_1apache_1_1hadoop_1_1tools_1_1rumen_1_1ParsedTaskAttempt.html). As their javadoc states:

> This is a wrapper class around LoggedTask (LoggedTaskAttempt). This provides also
>   the extra information about the task (task attempt) obtained from job history
>   which is not written to the JSON trace file.

It looks like, you'd have to extend Rumen to capture custom counters on your own.